# Laravel incomplete fields after data saving

Tags: php, laravel

I am not able to get all the fields after saving the data to the database.

**orders table**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->string('payment_method')->nullable();
            $table->string('payment_status')->default('pending');
            $table->string('order_status')->default('payment_pending');
            $table->longText('address');
            $table->text('note')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('total', 8, 2)->default(0);
            $table->dateTime('payment_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Order Modal**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'payment_method',
        'payment_status',
        'order_status',
        'address',
        'payment_at',
        'note',
        'total',
    ];
```

In my controller, I have the following functions:

```
public function createOrder($price)
    {
        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'address' => '123 Main St',
            'note' => 'dummy',
            'total' => $price
        ]);
    
    }
```

When I tried to save, I got the following output:

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "address": "123 Main St",
    "note": "dummy",
    "total": 548,
    "updated_at": "2022-08-02T12:55:47.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2022-08-02T12:55:47.000000Z",
    "id": 8
}
```

As you can see, I have got incomplete fields. How can I get all fields that can be null?
screenshot
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: are you encapsulating data in model?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of your table?

Comment: @Coola screenshot attached

Comment: Why is the note returning `null` when you are actually setting a value in your `createOrder`? That for me indicates something is not right - either in your post or in your application.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can try:

```
public function createOrder($price)
    {
        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'address' => '123 Main St',
            'note' => 'dummy',
            'total' => $price
        ]);


    dd(Order::find($order->id));
    }
```

Should give you all the fields, including null

Comment: I can do this also, but I don't want to run another query.

Comment: According to Laravel, the create method saves a new model and return the instance.
which mean will return all the fields that you added, not those who are null or default(if you didn't specify).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using null coalescing to enter fields which are null:

```php
public function createOrder($price)
    {
        $order = Order::create(
          [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'payment_method' => $payment_method ?? null,
        'payment_status' => $payment_status ?? null,
        'order_status' => $order_status ?? null,
        'address' => '123 Main St' ?? null,
        'payment_at' => $payment_at ?? null,
        'note' => $note ?? null,
        'total' => $price ?? null,
          ]
    );
    
    }
```

But its highly recommended you validate the fields before you call the create method. Validation will also give you the null values.

Answer (score 0):

Add the column you want to be return on the create

```
public function createOrder($price)
    {
        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'payment_method' => null,
            'payment_status' => null,
            'address' => '123 Main St',
            'note' => 'dummy',
            'total' => $price
        ]);
    
    }
```